Particle Effect, which works in the editor, does not work on Android
Hello everyone and good work. In my game, my character has a sword and a shield, and as I increase their level, they emit colorful steam. I add the particle effect of this vapor with code, and after adding it with the code, it throws the mesh of the object into the mesh renderer. When I try it in the editor, I do not have the slightest problem, but when I download it to the phone, the particle effect is added, but it does not cover my item. I think the reason for this is that the mesh renderer does not add the mesh of the object into it. If anyone knows what you think or knows the reason, I would be very grateful if you could help me.
This screenshot is from the editor. It covered the item as I wanted.

This screenshot is from the phone. If you look at the sword, particle effect has occurred, but since the mesh render is empty, it does not cover the weapon.

If I add the mesh into particle effect manually, it works normally as in the screenshot. But I don't want this, I have more than 60 weapons in the game and there are 4 types of steam colors, this would be ridiculous.

I'm very close to finishing my game and there are such problems. I don't understand whether it's not working as I wanted because I didn't set the Android settings properly. I would be very grateful if anyone who knows could help.
public class BuharKaplama : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject YanPanelGO;
    public GameObject Player;
    public Item item;
    public int slotsayi;
    Envanter er;
    El el;
    YanPanel YanPanel;
    private WaitForSeconds CeyrekSaniyeBekleme = new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
    public int IndexDegeri;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari());

        //StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5());
        //StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5K());
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);

        MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;

        //StopAllCoroutines();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);

        MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;

        YanPanel = YanPanelGO.GetComponent<YanPanel>();

        el = Player.GetComponent<El>();
        er = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Envanter").GetComponent<Envanter>();

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari());
        //StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5());
        //StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5K());
    }

    /*IEnumerator SilahBuhari1()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 20
                                         && !MaviBuharTF && !YesilBuharTF && !SariBuharTF && !KirmiziBuharTF);

        Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);

        MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1());
    }*/
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari()
    {
        yield return CeyrekSaniyeBekleme;

        //StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5());
        //StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4K());
        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5K());

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari2()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 20 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 40 &&
                                         !MaviBuharTF);

        MaviBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("MaviBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        MaviBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        MaviBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("MaviBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        MaviBuharTF = true;
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari3()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 40 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 60 &&
                                         !YesilBuharTF);
        //-------------
        /*Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);*/
        //-------------
        YesilBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("YesilBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        YesilBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        YesilBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("YesilBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        /*MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;*/
        YesilBuharTF = true;
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari4()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 60 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 80 &&
                                         !SariBuharTF);
        //-------------
        /*Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);*/
        //-------------
        SariBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("SariBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        SariBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        SariBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("SariBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        //MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = true;
        /*KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;*/
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari5()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 80 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[10].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde <= 100 &&
                                         !KirmiziBuharTF);
        //-------------
        /*Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);*/
        //-------------
        KirmiziBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("KirmiziBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        KirmiziBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        KirmiziBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("KirmiziBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        /*MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;*/
        KirmiziBuharTF = true;
        //YesilBuharTF = false;
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5());
    }
    

    //----------------------------------------

    /*IEnumerator SilahBuhari1K()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 20
                                         && !MaviBuharTF && !YesilBuharTF && !SariBuharTF && !KirmiziBuharTF);

        Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);

        MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari1K());
    }*/
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari2K()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 20 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 40 &&
                                         !MaviBuharTF);
        //-------------
        /*Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);*/
        //-------------
        MaviBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("MaviBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        MaviBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        MaviBuhar.SetActive(true);
        print("Şarta girdi");
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("MaviBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        MaviBuharTF = true;
       /* SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;*/
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2K());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari3K()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 40 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 60 &&
                                         !YesilBuharTF);
        //-------------
        /*Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(SariBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);*/
        //-------------
        YesilBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("YesilBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        YesilBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        YesilBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("YesilBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        /*MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = false;
        KirmiziBuharTF = false;*/
        YesilBuharTF = true;
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari3K());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari4K()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 60 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 80 &&
                                         !SariBuharTF);
        //-------------
        /*Destroy(MaviBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(KirmiziBuhar, 0f);
        Destroy(YesilBuhar, 0f);*/
        //-------------
        SariBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("SariBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        SariBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        SariBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("SariBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        //MaviBuharTF = false;
        SariBuharTF = true;
        /*KirmiziBuharTF = false;
        YesilBuharTF = false;*/
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari4K());
    }
    IEnumerator SilahBuhari5K()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                         gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 80 &&
                                         YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde <= 100 &&
                                         !KirmiziBuharTF);
        KirmiziBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("KirmiziBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
        KirmiziBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
        KirmiziBuhar.SetActive(true);
        //-------------
        if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("KirmiziBuhar"))
        {
            print("Girdi");
            ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
            var sh1 = ps1.shape;
            sh1.enabled = true;
            sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
            sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli;
            ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            ps1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
            print("Çıktı");
        }
        //-------------
        KirmiziBuharTF = true;
        //-------------

        StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari5K());
    }

    //----------------------------------------

    private GameObject MaviBuhar;
    private GameObject SariBuhar;
    private GameObject KirmiziBuhar;
    private GameObject YesilBuhar;

    private bool MaviBuharTF;
    private bool SariBuharTF;
    private bool KirmiziBuharTF;
    private bool YesilBuharTF;

    public MeshRenderer BedenSekli;
}

This is how it looks on mobile. Particle effect occurred but did not cover the item.

Look at this screenshot carefully because the mesh part of the shape part of the particle effect does not work empty.

When I put the mesh in it, it covered it as in the screenshot. I think the problem is that it doesn't fill up when I'm on mobile. It works when running the game in the editor. On my Android phone, steam does not cover the shield.

If you look at the screenshots, you can see the lines of code and the screenshot I took from mobile. In the text that appears on mobile, it appears that the mesh renderer inside particle effect is also filled, but the effect does not cover the shield. I wonder where the problem is, is there anyone out there who knows this? I'm sure someone with experience can solve this problem in two lines of code. It wasn't what I thought. Mesh rendering is assigned, but the shield is not covered.

This is the codes:
IEnumerator SilahBuhari2K()
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemismi.Contains(name) &&
                                     gameObject.activeSelf &&
                                     YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde >= 20 &&
                                     YanPanel.slotlar[11].GetComponent<EnvanterSlot>().item.itemyüzde < 40 &&
                                     !MaviBuharTF);

    MaviBuhar = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("MaviBuhar"), GetComponent<Transform>().position, GetComponent<Transform>().rotation);
    MaviBuhar.transform.parent = this.transform;
    MaviBuhar.SetActive(true);
    print("Şarta girdi");
    //-------------
    if (gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0].name.Contains("MaviBuhar"))
    {
        print("Girdi");
        ParticleSystem ps1 = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem>()[0];
        ps1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        ps1.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        rotationV.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        ps1.transform.localRotation = rotationV;
        var sh1 = ps1.shape;
        sh1.enabled = true;
        sh1.meshShapeType = ParticleSystemMeshShapeType.Triangle;
        sh1.shapeType = ParticleSystemShapeType.MeshRenderer;
        sh1.meshRenderer = BedenSekli.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        
        ParticleTransform = ps1.transform;
        print("Çıktı");
        if(sh1.meshRenderer == BedenSekli)
        {
            ItemIsmi = "MaviK" + " - " + sh1.meshRenderer.name.ToString();
        }
    }
    //-------------
    MaviBuharTF = true;
    //-------------

    StartCoroutine(SilahBuhari2K());
}



I think the problem is that when running on Android, the mesh renderer does not put the mesh into the mesh renderer, but the editor can put it into it. Probably a setting is off.

unrelated, but have you thought about using a shader rather than a particle system. It might look slightly different and not do exactly what you want but it may also be more performant.

I don't think so for now. Thank you for your advice.

Please include the settings you use for your particle system as well. Not everything works on mobile. Also that system with starting all those coroutines and wait for a state to destroy seems easily error prone

I had the right to upload one screenshot, so I did it in the part I thought was important. I know I don't write the code very well, but I'm just learning. As I gain experience, I will write better codes in the future.

I solved my problem. The reason is that the read/write feature of the model was not turned on.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/particle-effects-mesh-renderer-is-not-working.1575067/#post-9761464
